# Can I access Cassandra from Azure Website

Tags: azure, cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster on Azure and a nodejs websites using "node-cassandra-cql" package. It works with on my local machine. When i deploy the nodejs website to Azure websites - I get PoolConnectionError.

Can I access cassandra on some port from Azure Web Sites or I am restricted to using the managed databases there?

Comment: Check out Luke Tillman's http://www.killrvideo.com  It's an Azure/Cassandra demo site, with links to github for the code...that might help.

Comment: Link is dead, the article can be seen [HERE](http://www.luketillman.com/showing-off-cassandra-on-azure/) though

Answer (score 0):

when you say local machine, do you mean your nodejs site is on your local machine and it is able to connect to your cassandra cluster on azure?

Please let us know your azure website name.